# Why does Jest's toStrictEqual fail to match JSON responses made using the fetch API?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch-api

I was experimenting with Jest and the fetch API and discovered a strange behaviour.

Consider the route:

```js
debug.get('/echo', (req, res) => {
  const { value } = req.query;
  console.log(`[ ECHO ] ${value}`);
  res.json({ value });
});
```

And the test:

```js
it('echoes the given content', async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${URL}/debug/echo?value=hello`);
  const data = await res.json();
  expect(data).toStrictEqual({ value: 'hello' });
});
```

This produces the following output:

```
 FAIL  tests/debug.test.ts

  ● /debug/echo › echoes the given content

    expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: {"value": "hello"}
    Received: serializes to the same string

       8 |     const data = await res.json();
       9 |     console.log(data);
    > 10 |     expect(data).toStrictEqual({ value: 'hello' });
         |                  ^
      11 |   });
      12 | });
      13 |

      at Object.toStrictEqual (tests/debug.test.ts:10:18)
```

However, when I replace the `toStrictEqual` with a `toEqual`, the test passes as expected.

Why is this the case?

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: It appears to be the exact same, as indicated by the output of the test. When I `console.log` it, it prints as `{ value: 'hello' }` as expected.